# Getting the values of argument and function from the contour plot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

There is an equation F(T,x)=0, which is not solved analytically in the T(x) form. I contour plotted T(x) dependence. How the values of x and T(x) can be constructed in {`x_i`,`T(x_i)`} table form? I need 100 points on the contour plotted graphic.

Comment: See `Solve "f(x)=0" with a parameter` (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153966/9362)

Comment: @Tursinbay Are you satisfied with the answer provided? If yes, please accept it. If no, describe why/

Comment: Voting to leave open, since I reckon Alexei did a nice job of inferring OP's intent and providing fake data. Highly likely that there is a duplicate question though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solve \`f(x)=0\` with a parameter](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153854/solve-fx-0-with-a-parameter)

Answer (score 3):

I myself would apply the `FindRoot` wrapped with `Table` to do this. However, you are right that the `ContourPlot` also can be used. Since you gave no example, I will take the one from the Help/WolframDocumentation/ContourPlot, that is, the equation

```
eq=Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 1/2;
plt = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 1/2, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

[image]

This separates out the points forming the lines of the contour plot:

```
points = Cases[Normal@plt, Line[pts__] -> pts, Infinity];
```

Since we have here multiple lines, let us look at them such that we could select the one that we want to analyze:

```
    Manipulate[
 Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[{Black, Thin}], 
   Rectangle[{0, 0}, {13, 13}], Blue, Map[Line, points], Red, Thick, 
   Line[points[[n]]]}], {n, Range[9]}, ContentSize -> 250]
```

[image]

Here the value of n selects the part of the list points which contains the line in question. This line is highlighted by the red color. Let us take the central curve corresponding to n=9:

```
points[[9]]
```

Evaluate it. There are about 230 points. If you need only about 100 of them the following reduces their number:

```
lst = First /@ Partition[points[[9]], 2];
Length[lst]  

(* 115  *)
```

The list `lst`, thus, contains 115 points you need. Done.

Have fun!

Comment: `points[[9,;;;;2]]` might be a more idiomatic way to say "give me every other point". +1 otherwise.